# Get the total number of sections in beamer

Tags: beamer, macros, sectioning

In `beamer` you can use `\inserttotalframenumber` to print the total number of frames. Is there a command to print the total number of sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer stores this value in `\beamer@sectionmax`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sectionmax}{\the\beamer@sectionmax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{title}

\begin{frame}

\sectionmax

\end{frame}

\section{title}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, one can also use the `totcount` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{section}

\begin{document}

\section{title}

\begin{frame}

\total{section}

\end{frame}

\section{title}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```